# What is wrong with this code for generating random integers in Java??? (Unexpected Outputs)

Tags: java, eclipse, random, integer

The code below is supposed to generate random integers from 97 till 122:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    int a = (int)(Math.random()*(26 + 97));
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

The outputs I am getting are all over the place. They go below 97.
Here are the outputs for one of the runs:

```
33
113
87
73
22
25
118
29
16
21
```

Comment: yeah, this is more of a basic math problem than anything else^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a paren problem. Try this instead.

`(int)(Math.random()*26)` gives a number between 0 and 25 inclusive. 
Add 97 to that range and you get between 97 and 122 inclusive.

```
int a = (int)(Math.random()*26) + 97;
```